# PHP regexp values

Tags: php

My Regexp:

```
/^(\p{L}+)(?:\.(\p{L}+))*$/
```

and subject:

```
app.config.db
```

It returns matches `app` and `db`. Why this script omit `config`?

Comment: Throw your regex and input into https://www.regex101.com

Comment: Sorry i forgot ;) https://regex101.com/r/jI7cW4/1

Answer (score 2):

Because of this part:

```
(?:\.(\p{L}+))*
```

You're repeating a capturing group, which will only ever capture the **last** capture. You might want to look into [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all), which (with a different regex) would be able to return all of the matches.

Example:

```
$input = 'app.config.db';
$regex = '/\.?(\p{L}+)/';

preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => app
        [1] => config
        [2] => db
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex contains two capturing groups, so it will capture two strings. The first group (`^(\p{L}+)`) captures `app` because it's at the beginning of the string.

The second group initially captures `config`. But it's nested inside a `*`, so it repeats and captures `db`. In general, the result will be the *last* string captured by any group.

Comment: Is any solution to fix it?

Comment: @Mati Why not just split on `.`?

Comment: I would like to have 100% certainty (user can write this "queries")

Comment: @Mati You could validate the input first (with `/\A\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+)*\z/`), then split.

Comment: Yeah I will do it this way.